# First postLink() doesn't create form

Tags: php, cakephp, post

Using code that has been **baked into CRUD**, I have the following code for **deleting an item**:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller'=>'attachments', 'action' => 'delete', $attachment['Attachment']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete "%s?"', $attachment['Attachment']['name'])); ?>
```

The problem is that it lies **wrapped in a FORM tag**, and so what ends up happening is **Cake doesn't include the Form that the postLink would submit**.

Is there another way that still holds true to the integrity of Cake's infrastructure that would work even when I increase the security settings?  Probably needs to be a link to /attachment/delete/id, but baking for some reason chose to create a form and post it vs. creating a link, so I figured there was a reason for that and if so I want to uphold that reason.

Answer (score 6):

You probably didn't read the warnings in the doc block regarding this method
(http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink)

> This method creates a `<form>` element. So do not use this method inside an existing form.
>   Instead you should add a submit button using `FormHelper::submit()`

So don't do that. You would need to write to a buffer and output later (see [this closed PR](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/795)).

Comment: Update: There is now a way to write to the buffer since 2.5.0: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/d647fe8a91a9b2edca8cb411fa15562b3ed9b2c5

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in cakephp 3.0  `$this->Form->postLink()` was not working for first entry.

Then i do some R&D but not found any useful. Then i make some changes in form tag and `$this->Form->postLink()`. I remove the  `$this->Form->create()` from the .ctp files and use only `$this->Form->postLink();` and it start working.

Do not use the `$this->Form->postLink()` inside any other form tag 
    i.e `$this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['action' => 'ExportCustomers']]);`

If you want both then you have to adjust the `$this->Form->postLink()` and form tag according to it will not effect each other.